# Uploading video to google drive via frontend

Tags: php, front-end

I need to add a functionality to a website that I am developing which allows users to,

1. **Upload videos from a front-end form to google drive.**
2. **Save its shared URL/embedded code to the site's backend.**

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are both pretty broad questions in of themselves that should be asked seperately, but the first one is definitely not a WP question, it requires almost exclusively Google Drive API knowledge, the only WP part would be how to put enqueue javascript on the frontend

Comment: I have to do this in a wordpress website.

Comment: That doesn't make the Google Drive part a WP question. Figuring out how to interact with the Google Drive APIs is a Google API Q. There is nothing specific in WordPress that will assist you in this, much in the same way that a question about how to round the corners of a box in CSS is not a WP question, even if the box was on the homepage of a WP site. You need to check Google API documentation, Google API users, and Google Dev resources for how to talk to Google Drive. Even then, the question is actually several Q's, so it's too broad

Comment: If you do manage to implement a Google Drive uploader in JS, or learnt how to upload a file to Google drive in PHP, then how you might integrate that into a form in WP would be a good question to ask, and on topic. Additionally, how to embed Google Drive files in a post might be a good question if asked on its own

Comment: This question is not off-topic. I found the answer. If you can re-open this question, I can post the answer.

Comment: I won't argue in comments over wether this is or is not on topic, we have a process, If you disagree, you can open a question on the meta site https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Sorry sir, but I'm not arguring. I'm just requesting you to re-open the question so that I can post the answer. It maybe help others. Thank you.